# Execute function on another, already open, form

Tags: c#, winforms, function

I have a form with a datagridview inside of it.

When you doubleclick on a row from the datagridview, another form will open, which is basically a form where you can edit the data you just double-clicked.

There are a 3 buttons in this "edit" form, a delete, update and a return to main form button.

When finished with what you were supposed to do on this form, it closes.

My question is;

When this form closes, I want the data that is inside of the datagridview in the main form to refresh, how can I call that function on the main form from the edit form.

Keep in mind that I already have a reload function, let's say it's called refreshData();.

Comment: Did you open the form using `.Show()` or `.ShowDialog()` ?

Comment: Pass the method as a delegate to the constructor of the new Form/Dialog window, invoke when you please.

Comment: I used .ShowDialog()

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used .ShowDialog(), then just put the refresh function under this line of code.

The program will continue with the

```
private void cell1_DoubleClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
```

function.

So your code will look similair to this;

```
private void cell1_DoubleClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     //Your previous code ....

     //The part where you open the EditForm
     MyEditForm.ShowDialog();

     //After it has been closed the program will continue to execute this function(if it has not been ended yet)
     RefreshData();
     //Since this function is running from your main form, the function RefreshData() will be executed on your main form aswell
}
```

No need to check some dialog results at all.

Answer (score 2):

if you open the edit form as a modal window, the ShowDialog() call is blocking, so if you put the refreshData call after that it will execute after the edit form is closed:

```
var editForm = new EditForm(...);
var result = editForm.ShowDialog();
if (result == DialogResult.OK)
{
    refreshData(); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this will work:

Add a property DatagridviewForm of type DatagridviewForm (you have probably an other name/type) to AnotherForm. In the part where you call anotherForm.ShowDialog, add the following code:

```
anotherForm = new AnotherForm();
anotherForm.DatagridviewForm = this;
anotherForm.ShowDialog();
anotherForm.Dispose();
```

In the close handler of AnotherForm, update or refresh the data:

```
private void AnotherForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)   
{ 
    DatagridviewForm.refreshData();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the data when the form is closing

```
Form MyEditForm;

private void cell1_DoubleClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
     if (MyEditForm==null)
     { 
         MyEditForm=new MyEditForm();
         MyEditForm.FormClosing += refreshData;
     }
     MyEditForm.ShowDialog();
}

private void refreshData(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var myDataObj=MyEditForm.getData();
}
```